# \vbox badness helvetica 12pt and 1.5 spacing

Tags: spacing, fontsize, geometry, layout, badness

My university asks for 1.5 spacings, and at least 2cm left and right. I'd like to use arial and a header as stated below.

Now, I get `\vbox badness` and I read this means pages are badly defined.

But what is the proper page layout? How do I figure that out? So what do I have to set bottom and/or top in the `geometry` package, so everything is properly shown?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{csquotes}


%% use arial
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

%% use 1.5 spacing
\linespread{1.5}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% Outer layout
\usepackage[a4paper,width=160mm,top=25mm,bottom=35mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% redefining chapter numbers
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{20\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        %\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \Huge\bfseries \thechapter.\space%
        %\par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother


% in the book class, the first page of a chapter uses the plain style. Hence, redefining the plain style with fancyhdr
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}} %makes Chapter 1 dissapear in header
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt} % this adjusts header higth since otherwise headersize too small

\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
```

(For example, setting bottom to 15mm doesnt show a badness but that doesnt look good)

Comment: I think the 'looking good' part is most important, if you get `\vbox badness` warnings but you are satisfied with the result then you can safely ignore the warnings.

Comment: You're not using Arial, but Helvetica… Also 1.5 spacing is not exactlly the same as \linespread{1.5}, because you have to take into accountfootnotes, the spacing of tables and figures, etc. Better load `setspace`and add the `\onehalfspacing` directive.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Helvetica is what I use.. the usage of Arial seems complicated, as I have to compile it differently and then I get a lot of errors. But```\linespread{1.5}``` produces the results I need. ```setspace``` ```\onehalfspacing``` is too small. But how can I add to 15mm, so I can increase the bottom?